# How to prevent lxml remove method from removing text between two elements

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I'm using lxml and python 2.7 to parse xml files. I need to use remove method to remove an element at some point, but very strangely it removes some text after it as well.

the input xml is:

```
<ce:para view="all">Web and grid services <ce:cross-refs refid="BIB10 BIB11">[10,11]</ce:cross-refs>, where they can provide rich service descriptions that can help in locating suitable services.</ce:para>
```

then I need to expand the `cross-refs` element to multiple `cross-ref` with separated `refid`. So the output should be something like this:

```
<ce:para view="all">Web and grid services <ce:cross-ref refid="BIB10">[10]</ce:cross-ref><ce:cross-ref refid="BIB11">[11]</ce:cross-ref>, where they can provide rich service descriptions that can help in locating suitable services.</ce:para>
```

and here's the python the code with some abbreviation:

```
xpath = "//ce:cross-refs"
cross_refs = tree.xpath(xpath, namespaces={'ce': 'http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd'})
for c in cross_refs:
    c_parent = c.getparent()
    c_values = c.text.strip("[]")
    ...
    ref_ids = c.attrib['refid'].strip().split()
    i = 0
    for r in ref_ids:
        ...
        tag = et.QName(CE, 'cross-ref')
        exploded_cross_refs = et.Element(tag, refid=r, nsmap=NS_MAP)
        exploded_cross_refs.text = "[" + c_values[i] + "]"
        c.addprevious(exploded_cross_refs)
        i += 1
    c_parent.remove(c)
```

which gets `cross-refs` element, expand `refid` values and element text values, and then creates new `cross-ref` elements and add them before the original `cross-refs` and finally I want to remove old `cross-refs` element and my problem is exactly here: When I remove this element, the text between the closing tag and next element gets removed as well, so the final result is like this:

```
<ce:para view="all">Web and grid services <ce:cross-ref refid="BIB10">[10]</ce:cross-ref><ce:cross-ref refid="BIB11">[11]</ce:cross-ref></ce:para>
```

Notice that the text between last `cross-ref` and `para` element has been removed! How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, especially in case *not all* elements of certain name within a certain parent need to be removed, we can create simple method that will append the tail to previous element, if any, or append it to the parent's text otherwise, before the element actually get removed :

```
def remove_preserve_tail(element):
    if element.tail:
        prev = element.getprevious()
        parent = element.getparent()
        if prev is not None:
            prev.tail = (prev.tail or '') + element.tail
        else:
            parent.text = (parent.text or '') + element.tail
    parent.remove(element)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> raw = '''<root>
... foo
... <div></div>has tail and no prev
... <br/><div></div>has tail and prev
... <br/>
... <div>no tail, whitespaces only</div>
... </root>'''
... 
>>> root = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> divs = root.xpath("//div")
>>> for div in divs:
...     remove_preserve_tail(div)
... 
>>> print etree.tostring(root)
<root>
foo
has tail and no prev
<br/>has tail and prev
<br/>

</root>
```

Comment: I guess in my case, which I need to remove all `corss-refs` elements, `strip_elements` run faster with cleaner code. right?

Comment: Yes, your approach is likely to be faster, and surely has a cleaner code. And for that particular case, I'd go with your approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems `remove` method, removes `element.tail` by default. So I replaced the `remove` with `strip_elements` method which takes a `with_tail` argument, so you have control on removing tail or not. here's the [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_elements), and here's the command I used:

```
et.strip_elements(c_parent, 'cross-refs', with_tail=False)
```